# How exactly does a program talk to a device driver?

Tags: operating-system, driver, device-driver, hardware

So I'm confused on how exactly we as the programmers talk to devices on the computer. Now I'm not talking the big ideas. I know that there are device drivers that sit atop the hardware so that different programs can use there features.

But in general who exactly talks to the drivers? Is the programmer writing the application responsible for calling a function on the driver? Or does the programmer call a function through the operating system which then handles the call to the driver? As you can see I'm really just confused about the nitty gritty of how the driver, OS and your application fit together.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919267.aspx Here's a nice diagram from a flavour of windows.

Answer (score 2):

The application doesn't call the driver directly - that would violate the entire idea of user mode and kernel separation. Instead the OS exposes the relevant [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) to the user mode programs, enabling the applications to call the exposed functionality (with respect to the predefined restrictions that should be documented).